# Drag marks from piano wheels, how to fix?

Tags: hardwood-floor

Recently we tried to move our piano across our floor by rolling it but to our chagrin the weight of the piano left indented rolling marks on our lovely wooden floor. They are all over about 1/6th of our living floor. Some are drag marks, i.e. the markings are NOT smooth. Most of them are smooth indented rolling marks about 1/16 - 1/7 in depth by my estimates.

Is there an easy fix for this or do I have to sand down the entire floor by that much? Ir can I just sand down that area...but then we would be left with I leveled floors.

I’m really frustrated because I have to see these marks everyday. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have heard you can use a steam iron on smaller nicks and dings.  Put a towel down on the floor then keep iron moving on the towel to avoid burning the wood, try a few spots, might be surprised with results.

Comment: I beleive a damp towel or cloth (rather than dry) helps. It seemed to when I tried it.